# Java: Split an int into separate variables

Tags: java

I need to split an int into separate variables.
For instance x=356     a=3|| b=5 || c=6

I have already solved it for 3 digit numbers only, but my program does not work for 2 digit or 4 digit numbers etc.

P.S.
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (number > 0){
digit = number %10;
number/=10;
digits.add(digit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
int test = 12345;
String test2 = String.valueOf(test);
for(int x = 0; x < test2.length(); x++) {       
    System.out.println(test2.charAt(x));
}
```